# Diagnosing zero-window TCP error causing connection reset with embedded microchip TCP/IP stack

Tags: c, tcp, embedded, wireshark, microchip

I'm working on a project to replace an existing embedded linux device with the same functionality with new hardware. We have transitioned to a Microchip wifi module (WFI32E01) running their TCP stack and performance has been fine as we are just communicating with Windows software via HTTP. It also needs to be backwards compatible with another piece of Windows SW and I'm experiencing disconnection/re-connection due to what seems like full buffers. Communication between our Windows program and the device is fine. No out of order packets or resets. Communication between another Windows program and the device is flawed shown in the image below and causing resets of the connection.

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S3oT.png)

I interpret the capture as Windows (192.168.211.10) stating that its window is full. The reason it confuses me is that the device only responds to the HTTP request from the Windows software so I wouldn't think that there would be enough throughput to fill up the window buffer. This windows software works fine with the previous device version which indicates that it's probably the new device that is at fault and yet the error seems to be on the Windows side. 192.168.211.1 is the I of the embedded device running the DHCP server. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction

**Extra Info:**

[V1 Legacy HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbjv.png)

[V1 Legacy HTTP Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfBgp.png)

[V2 New Device Microchip HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rwpH.png)

[V2 New Device Microchip HTTP Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRSGm.png)

The HTTP request with the original V1 device includes a "keep-alive" header which I believe is redundant in HTTP1.1 but is still not present from the same windows PC to the new hardware device. The V1 device response has HTTP1.0 and HTTP1.1 but I can't figure out why and if I should try to copy that.

Some more wireshark captures including fully expanded HTTP headers.

[V2 Successful HTTP transaction - request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qV7n.png)

[V2 Successful HTTP transaction - response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4PYj.png)

[V2 Failed HTTP transaction - request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNPY2.png)

Comparison of HTTP request from V1 and V2 devices. Notice how Windows request to the V1 device (on the right) sends a "keep-alive" while when requesting to the V2 device (on the left) it doesn't send this. Why should there be a difference?

[V1/V2 HTTP request comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Mxr.png)

[V1/V2 HTTP/TCP packet order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEZs.png)

Comment: Something is wrong with your trace - there's a package missing in place of the duplicated `FIN/ACK` package. Which end did capture this trace?

Comment: It appears that the failure occurs after the new device should be closing the TCP connection - but everything is behaving correctly when your own application is the one to close a connection?

Comment: This was captured on Windows which is the same machine the problem SW is running on. Well the connection shouldn't be resetting like this. I'm still learning about TCP but I don't believe the connection should be closing at all. I'm quite confused on what would cause the "zero-window" error as it doesn't occur at all with same device running our own Windows software on the same machine.

Comment: The "zero window" isn't really happening - it's just how Wireshark is interpreting the double-ack following the double-fin. And the Windows TCP stack has interpolated the sequence number on the incorrectly duplicated FIN package.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. How would you suggest I go about fixing this then? I assume the problem is on the embedded device side but the tcp stack being somewhat complex I'm not sure where to start. Also weird that it's happening with one windows SW but not the other. Unless it's to do with the frequency of the requests.

Comment: You are looking for a fault in the TCP stack implementation around the regular server side close of the socket. The difference between the applications is most likely simply a different request header in HTTP (Connection keep-alive vs no keep-alive), which controls whether the server closes the socket or not.

Comment: I have some more useful information now I think. The Windows SW client is not sending "keep-alive" to the new device while it does to the old device. I'm not sure why it would change its behavior like that. Another oddity is that the HTTP requests are numbered "HTTP Request 1/2" then 2/2 after which the connection is closed and the cycle repeats. I can go to the software developers and ask them to fix this but I just want to make sure it's not a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what is happening there:

1. a connection is being made, starting at packet 7.  The connection establishement is correctly ended with packet 9.  The hosts are at port 62121 (client, windows, advertising a window size ---probably its buffer size--- of 64240), and 80 (the sensor device, acting as a server) advertising a window of 1024 (common for small devices)
2. two HTTP requests are made to get the same resource, some temperature, with a delay between them of 5s.
3. An end of connection is requested in packet 16 by the windows client process.  This is the start of the client process closing sequence.  The data is acknowledged in packet 17, and the FIN is acknowledged separately in packet 20.
4. An extra packet (probably a repeat of packet 17 is sent ---it seems automatically, as there's almost no delay between both, not needed but many implementations do it to ensure better connection close)
5. The reset comes as a response to packet 21 (the zero window packet) that is sent after both ends have acknowledged their FINs which happens after packet 20. This packet should never be sent and the RST is correctly sent by the device. After packet 16, it is still valid for the client to send a window size of 0 (but undesirable, it is better to allow the packet flow, just to ignore it, than to make the sender to retain a packet that will not be possible to deliver), but never after the FIN packet 20 is received from the server, (it signals no more data is to be sent, so announcing a window size of 0 after it has been received, will produce a failure in the protocol, and the RST message will be appropiate) The window size of 0 is clearly illegal, as it is sent AFTER the FIN so it is clearly out of the connection context.  This is clearly a misinterpretation of the TCP protocol, in relation to window size signalling, which is only a flow control resource and never a closing flow of data.

As a note, there's no full buffer situations here.... the buffers at both sides are bigger than 1024 bytes, and the full connection is transferring a total of 215 bytes (per the two http requests made). (the SYN/FIN flags count as one byte each, making a total sequencing of 217 in the wireshark output)  the window zero packet is probably sent as a security net by the client software ---but it misinterprets the use of the window and fails the protocol, being sent out of a connection--- to cope with a probably unrelated bug.  Windows software is known to have buggy implementations of TCP.

Comment: Hi Luis. Thank you for your explanation as it does make a lot of sense. I have included an edit with some more screenshots comparing the V1 and V2 devices and some differences I noticed between them. I'm cautious to make too many changes to the microchip TCP stack and I don't want to become non-compliant to the standard but I do need to make it compatible with the windows TCP implementation. Is it wise to try removing the "cache-control" and "content-length" in the header or am I missing the point?

Comment: HTTP has no relationship to TCP but just as any other user protocol of the TCP module.  Based on this, the observed packets are correctly dealt witth in the microchip device and the incorrectly working implementation is the Windows client you introduced in the end of your question.  It's incorrect to send a window change once you have been notified the end of the connection and the RST packet is just the correct behavior when such a thing happens.  You can safely IGNORE this behaviour (which is why Microsoft doesn't actually correct it) and it will not affect the TCP stream.   (continues)...

Comment: The tcp stream is not affected because all this happens AFTER the connection has been closed and acknowledged at both ends, so is not worth doing anything, but observing some noise in the traffic analisys.  IMHO you shouldn't observe anything at the HTTP level, did you?

Comment: So I'm not touching the microchip TCP stack but I do have to slightly customize the HTTP server code for my application. What I'm observing is in this 3rd party windows SW the device greys out and "disconnects" for about 5 seconds at a time. This seems to be caused by the "RST" and for the application is an unacceptable behaviour. I may be incorrectly identifying the HTTP code as the problem but am just trying to fix this behaviour by the system since I can't touch the client SW.

Comment: No. The reset is sent in response to the window change, and is actually the right thing to do, as the window change is sent out of the connection context.  You are wrongly identifyiing the bad guy.  Not sending the RST will make your microchip a bad guy also, while the windows is misbehaviing outside of a connection, that's not to affect anything inside it.  But not sending the appropiate RST will make your TCP implementation non-compliant.  And this will affect also non HTTP connections.  If you have identified some HTTP issue, it is clearly unrelated to this issue.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean with _the device greys out and disconnects_  Who is disconnecting and what reason is used at all?  If it is an HTTP issue, then you should check the HTTP data, not the TCP implementation (which up to my knowldege is not failing)  Can you provide to your question the actual contents of the HTTP request (including headers) and the response headers?

Comment: So in this 3rd party windows software the device connects to it greys out control of the device seemingly at the same time as the RST of the connection. I understand this seems vague but just giving you some context for the symptom of the problem that seems to relate to the TCP connection reset. This is why I thought the problem was the RST. I have added what I think you're asking for. There is no "response" to the HTTP request when the TCP connection resets. The next HTTP message is a new request from the client.

Comment: If there's a way to send the full wireshark capture I'm happy to provide it. I have fully expanded the HTTP messages so hopefully that's sufficient.

Comment: I've found what seems to be an important difference between the V1 device and V2 which I have also added. Windows software sends HTTP request and gets a response from V1 device. Windows then "ACK" then "FIN,ACK" followed by "ACK" from the device and gracefully closing the connection. With the new device after the HTTP transaction windows sends "ACK" followed immediately by a new HTTP request and only then "FIN,ACK".

Comment: After the ACK corresponding to the last FIN has been received at both ends, the connection is actually ended.  This is something that has already happened when the window change is sent, and so, the RST is not only acceptable, but REQUIRED by the TCP specs.  It's impossible to observe anything in the upper layer (in the app), as both processes must have been signalled about the connection closed event.  So everything observed inside the connection (all the HTTP stuff) IS COMPLETELY UNRELATED  to the sending of the RST or the window change. I cannot explain this clearer, but only LOUDER :)